# Upgrade php version on centos 6.5

Tags: centos, php, yum, php5, centos6.5

On the current stack i hv
centos 6.5 (64 bit) ,  PHP 5.3 available.

I'm a linux new bee & need to perform php upgrade to PHP 5.5.

Tried following but that returned error:

`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
    wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
    rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm`

then under `remi-php55` section ( in `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`)
`enabled=1`
then `yum clean all`
 
`yum update -y`

This returned error as pasted in following pastebin http://pastebin.com/ehuHibhy

and php did not upgraded , any workaround how to achieve this?

Edit 1:

Enabling the remi repo alongwith remi-php55 resulted in stripping php repo errors.

Updated trace: http://pastebin.com/J8sN5Z9Z

However, PHP Version isn't yet upgraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You enabled the remi-php55 repo, but that depends on the remi repo also being enabled. You need to enable this as well.

Comment: cool, so doing that reduced the errors to this 
http://pastebin.com/J8sN5Z9Z (removing php errors , and now only perl repo errors are shown)

Comment: Well that's a whole separate issue.

Comment: but that didn't upgraded the php version yet

Comment: You didn't do what it told you to do!

Comment: Thank you very much. so i skipped the perl dependency and the php version is upgraded. I was able to login to zpanel as well :)

However there were warning regarding Php Modules - unable to initialize (module api mismatch) http://pastebin.com/BZ4TKJpp

Comment: now Do i hv to manually compile each php module i need??

Comment: As someone else already mentioned, you need to get rid of zpanel.

Comment: I understand, but I inherited this centos box from previous administrator and I really need to fix this without removing the admin panel. Your answers helped a lot so far. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be trying to upgrade individual components like this when you've got cPanel or Plesk installed. They control all aspects of the server and you should be upgrading PHP the way they support.

Comment: Zpanel is there, but it dosn't hv any option to upgrade the php from inside it.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `yum list '*php*'`?

Comment: pastebin link of output http://pastebin.com/ihCXGUcH

Answer (score 0):

If you can limit yourself at PHP 5.4, you can use the "software collection (SCL)" repository. This report will sideload newer package version (eg: php54) that you can use on process-by-process base.

In short:

1. **enable SCL repo**

> yum install -y centos-release-SCL.x86_64
>   yum install -y php54.x86_64 php54-php-mysqlnd

2. **create a PHP wrapper script in /var/www/cgi-bin/php54-wrapper**

   `#!/bin/bash
   source /opt/rh/php54/enable
   exec php-cgi`
3. **give appropriate permission to the wrapper script**

> restorecon -RF /var/www/cgi-bin/php54-wrapper
>   chown apache:apache /var/www/cgi-bin/php54-wrapper
>   chmod ugo-rwx /var/www/cgi-bin/php54-wrapper
>   chmod ug+rx /var/www/cgi-bin/php54-wrapper

4. **configure the appropriate virtualhost to use the new php version**

   `AddHandler php-cgi .php
   Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php54-wrapper
   <Location />
   Options +ExecCGI
   </Location>`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This could certainly help but as of now, This box needs minimum php5.5 (web app specific requirements) :-)